# Compare values in one column with another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison

`A2` has `cotton,leather`

`B2` has `Leather,wool,cotton`

I need to see if **all** values in `A2` is present in `B2` irrespective of **case** or **order** or any extra values in `B2`.

So i need a formula which says present in `C2` for the above example.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&LOWER(TRIM(A2))&",", ","&LOWER(TRIM(B2))&","))), "present", "not present")
```

this formula works if it's in order. but for the above example it says not present.

Few other examples are:

| Column A | Column B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cotton,leather | Leather,wool,cotton | Present |
| red | red,blue | Present |
| cotton candy,pink | pink,red,cotton candy | Present |
| blue | red,yellow | Not Present |
| Infant,toddler | Baby,Toddler | Not Present |
| Adult,Baby,Taller,Kidder | Adult,Kid | Not Present |
| Steel | Alloy Steel,Wood | Not Present |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd> & <kbd>SEARCH()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(
    OR(
    ISERROR(
    SEARCH(
    ","&TEXTSPLIT(A2,",")&",",","&B2&","))),
    "Not ","")
    &"Present"
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(
    AND(
    ISNUMBER(
    SEARCH(
    ","&TEXTSPLIT(A2,",")&",",","&B2&","))),
    "","Not ")
    &"Present"
```

---

Try using <kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(
    AND(
    ISNUMBER(
    SEARCH(
    ","&FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b")&",",","&B2&","))),
    "Present","Not Present"
    )
```

---

**Note:** Based on your Excel Version one needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

To learn more on <kbd>FILTERXML()</kbd> highlighly recommended post exclusively by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) Sir**:

**[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)**

---